# Chrome prevents the site due to ads

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, ads

I'm facing a problem just with google chrome. My website home page works properly, but when trying to open a post on the site, it shows this message:

[Security Wrror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ia8U.png)

The site is based on the latest WordPress version, and it works properly with all other browsers. I tried to remove ads (the only way to get the required fund). but nothing changed. It still doesn't open on Google Chrome.

I tried to update the sitemap, but nothing changed.

I hope you can help. Most of the visitors use Google Chrome as a default browser, and this is a major problem because we earn money due to ads viewed on the site.

[here a link to my website](http://sklns.com)

Comment: without seeing the site this is impossible to diagnose

Comment: i updated the post and put a link to the site, forgive me i've forgotten xD

Comment: i'm on chrome, page loads fine?

Comment: it loads just the home page, any other post on the site wouldn't open, would you recheck please !

Comment: "The site ahead contains harmful programs"

your site contains malware

Comment: I only put some ads, nothing more !, I deleted them then checked in Google safe browsing and still harmful